# Not all points are appearing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I did this code

- I want to display a list of float(points in the map)
- But only the first point appears the others didn't. The path between the points is hidden also and I don't know why.

  @model IList
  @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lay2.cshtml";}
   var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");}

  ```
  @for (int marker=2;marker<@Model.Count; marker++) 
  {
  <script type="text/javascript">
      alert(@marker);
      var myOptions = {zoom: 30, center: myLatLng, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
           new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[marker].ToString(culture), @Model[marker + 1].ToString(culture)),];
      var flightmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[marker].ToString(culture), @Model[marker + 1].ToString(culture)),
              map: map,
              title: " denden" });var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
              path: flightPlanCoordinates,
              strokeColor: "#FF0000",
              strokeOpacity: 1.0,
              strokeWeight: 2
          });
      flightPath.setMap(map);
  </script>

  marker++; 

  }
  ```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: I notice that you call 'marker++' after you close your script tag and that you are also incrementing marker in the for loop initializer. If i'm correct, marker would be 2 for the first round, then 4 the second time through. Is this desired? Also, why start marker at 2 and not 0?

Comment: possible duplicate of [error javascrit display points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12449549/error-javascrit-display-points)

Comment: @Esteban is right, if you want to increment by 2 each iteration, use marker = marker+2 in the loopinitializer

Comment: because the IList<float> contains <(latitude first point),(longitude first point),(lat second point),(long second point)........etc >

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're recreating your map with each iteration of your loop.  Maybe try something like this:

```
@model IList<float>
  @{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Lay2.cshtml";
 var culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");}
 <body  onload="initialize(@Model[0].ToString(culture), @Model[1].ToString(culture))">
 <table style="width: 100%; height: 70%"> <tr>
    <td style="width: 100%"><div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div></td>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var myOptions = {zoom: 30,
                center: myLatLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
             myOptions);
            @for (int marker=2;marker<@Model.Count; marker += 2) {
            var flightPlanCoordinates = [
             new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[marker].ToString(culture), @Model[marker + 1].ToString(culture)),];
            var flightmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(@Model[marker].ToString(culture), @Model[marker + 1].ToString(culture)),
                map: map,
                title: " denden" });var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                strokeColor: "#FF0000",
                strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                strokeWeight: 2
            });
            flightPath.setMap(map);
            }
        </script>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds about right. I improved the formatting and then noticed it too.

Comment: He is also writing duplicate flightPlanCoordinates and flightmarker variables to the page each iteration. Must be js errors in console.

Comment: the problem is the only first point is appeared ( @Model[0]=latitude 1st point and @Model[1] = longitude 1st point)